# Notation to describe amount of relevant elements in a tuple?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, notation

Say, we have the set $A=\{♠,♣,♥,♦\}^3$ and would like to define the following map:

\begin{align} 
f: A &\to \{0,1,2,3\}
 \\ a &\mapsto \text{amount of ♥'s in the tuple } a
\end{align}

For example, $f(♣,♣,♥)=1$ and $f(♥,♦,♥)=2$. What notation could one use in this case?

Comment: What you just used to describe the question is perfect.

Comment: @Berci: Thank you! I just thought maybe there is a handy notation which I'm not aware of.

Comment: Little comment, there can also be $0$ hearts in the tuple $a$, so  $0$ should be included in the image of $f$.

Comment: @user112167: Oh, indeed! Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B=\{♥\}$ then $f(x,y,z) = 1_{x\in B}+1_{y\in B}+1_{z\in B}$. Where $1_{x\in B}$ is the indicator function, it equals $1$ if $x\in B$ and $0$ if $x \notin B$.
Is this the notation you want? Also a nice notation (in my opinion) would be:
$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{k}1_{x_i\in B}$. Where $x$ is a vector with components from $A^k$. This would generalize the function and makes it compact.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought of the indicator function in this context. The notation is nice, yet I was wondering if there is some shortcut notation, customary to such problems (which are mostly from combinatorics, I guess).

Comment: Made a edit for such that the notation is more compact and the function $f$ now can contain a random number of variables. Is this what you mean by shortcut notation?